# Use JsonProperty With Blazor

Tags: blazor-client-side

I've been trying to get Blazor to use custom property names using the Newtonsoft.Json 'JsonProperty' attribute but so far cannot find a way to make it work. If I create an initial Blazor WebAssembly using the template and modify the 'WeatherForecast' class to...

```
public class WeatherForecast
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sum")] 
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}
```

The summary is no longer displayed in the grid even though I can see the data with a 'sum' field in the response. Does anyone no how I can get the model to bind correctly within the client?

Answer (score 2):

Blazor [switched to System.Text.Json in 3.0-beta6](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12685). If you just want to rename a field, use the `JsonPropertyName` attribute instead:

```cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class WeatherForecast
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("sum")] 
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}
```

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12685) for allowing use of Newtonsoft.Json.